# Kafka connect multiple workers with same connect topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm running the Kafka connect in distributed mode. There are 3 workers. All of them having same configuration like group id and connect topic names (connect offset, status, config).

My use case is running a Debezium connector (6 connectors) to extract data from 6 different MySQL servers.

Is it a good practice to maintain them in the same Kafka topic (I mean the offsets and all)?

Comment: How else would you configure it? Have one connect instance (with 3 internal topics) for each connector for a total of 18 internal topics + 6 topics being written to?

Comment: No no, 1 worker 3 topics. And 3 workes - total 9 topics. But I'm just asking the best practice.

Comment: From experience, we've had hundreds of connectors on 20 workers max (although it was in an auto-scaling group), and the 3 internal topics were able to handle that just fine processing hundreds of GB of data per hour for maybe 50+ connectors

Comment: Granted, those were mostly S3 sinks for the analytics team, but I doubt Debezium should be much different